# ContentFrame.Navigate uri, page not found

Tags: silverlight, mapping, uri

When I click a button on my silverlight website I want my ContentFrame to navigate to a different page (to the About.xaml). I do this using the following code.

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/About.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And my ContentFrame looks like this

```
    <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="/Home" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
        <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
            <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
            </uriMapper:UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame>
```

However when I press the button I get the error message:

> Page not found: "/Views/About"

My project looks like this:

[image: navigation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/About", UriKind.Relative));
```

The Uri mapper should add the path and the extension for you.